# python unittest.TestCase.assertEquals() on complex data structures

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, rounding

I'm unit testing a function that returns a *very* complex data structure (dict of lists of lists of sets etc.). I validated the output manually, and now I want to make sure it doesn't change without me noticing.

Right now I have:

```
   self.assertEquals(data,
        {'Instr1': {'COUPON_LIST': '0 % SEMI 30/360',
                    'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_XS0181523803',
                    'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
                    'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': -1.9/100,
                                           'THEO/PV01': -1500.15,
                                           'THEO/Value': 0.333,
                                           'THEO/Yield': 3.3/100},
                                  'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': -2.2/100,
                                         'THEO/PV01': -1000.1,
                                         'THEO/Value': 0.111,
                                         'THEO/Yield': 5.5/100}}},
         'Instr2': {'COUPON_LIST': None,
                    'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_US059512AJ22',
                    'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
                    'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
                                           'THEO/PV01': None,
                                           'THEO/Value': 1.0,
                                           'THEO/Yield': 0.0},
                                  'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
                                         'THEO/PV01': -15.15,
                                         'THEO/Value': 4055.344,
                                         'THEO/Yield': 4.4/100}}},
         'Instr3': {'COUPON_LIST': '0 % SEMI 30/360',
                    'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_XS0181523803',
                    'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
                    'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': -1.9/100,
                                           'THEO/PV01': -1500.15,
                                           'THEO/Value': 0.333,
                                           'THEO/Yield': 3.3/100},
                                  'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': -2.2/100,
                                         'THEO/PV01': -1000.1,
                                         'THEO/Value': 0.111,
                                         'THEO/Yield': 5.5/100}}},
         'Instr4': {'COUPON_LIST': None,
                    'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_US059512AJ22',
                    'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
                    'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
                                           'THEO/PV01': None,
                                           'THEO/Value': 1.0,
                                           'THEO/Yield': 0.0},
                                  'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
                                         'THEO/PV01': -15.15,
                                         'THEO/Value': 4055.344,
                                         'THEO/Yield': 4.4/100}}}}
```

I have two problems:

1. the tested class is not stable and the data CAN change. In that case, I want to quickly pinpoint where the output changed, and only validate the differences. E.g. I'm looking for a nice output saying

   data['Instr1']['MATURITY_DATE']: '2014/12/31' != '31/12/2014'

   data['Instr5']: node not found in lhs

   but at the same time I do not want to manually test every single node of the structure.
2. as you can see some elements are float, and 4.4/100 != 0.044. I need logic that runs AssertAlmostEqual on float nodes, and AssertEqual on everything else.

Is there any library that does this, or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 1):

A *quick and dirty* solution is to compare the pretty-print representations of the data using `difflib`. However this solution is absolutely *not* robust:

```
In [22]: import copy
    ...: import difflib
    ...: import pprint
    ...:
In [23]: data = {'Instr1': {'COUPON_LIST': '0 % SEMI 30/360',
    ...:                     'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_XS0181523803',
    ...:                     'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
    ...:                     'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': -1.9/100,
    ...:                                            'THEO/PV01': -1500.15,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Value': 0.333,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Yield': 3.3/100},
    ...:                                   'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': -2.2/100,
    ...:                                          'THEO/PV01': -1000.1,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Value': 0.111,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Yield': 5.5/100}}},
    ...:          'Instr2': {'COUPON_LIST': None,
    ...:                     'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_US059512AJ22',
    ...:                     'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
    ...:                     'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
    ...:                                            'THEO/PV01': None,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Value': 1.0,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Yield': 0.0},
    ...:                                   'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
    ...:                                          'THEO/PV01': -15.15,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Value': 4055.344,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Yield': 4.4/100}}},
    ...:          'Instr3': {'COUPON_LIST': '0 % SEMI 30/360',
    ...:                     'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_XS0181523803',
    ...:                     'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
    ...:                     'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': -1.9/100,
    ...:                                            'THEO/PV01': -1500.15,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Value': 0.333,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Yield': 3.3/100},
    ...:                                   'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': -2.2/100,
    ...:                                          'THEO/PV01': -1000.1,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Value': 0.111,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Yield': 5.5/100}}},
    ...:          'Instr4': {'COUPON_LIST': None,
    ...:                     'LEGAL_ENTITY': 'LE_US059512AJ22',
    ...:                     'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
    ...:                     'scenarios': {'Base': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
    ...:                                            'THEO/PV01': None,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Value': 1.0,
    ...:                                            'THEO/Yield': 0.0},
    ...:                                   'UP': {'Spread Over Yield': None,
    ...:                                          'THEO/PV01': -15.15,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Value': 4055.344,
    ...:                                          'THEO/Yield': 4.4/100}}}}

In [24]: data_repr = pprint.pformat(data)

In [25]: data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)

In [26]: data2['Instr1']['MATURITY_DATE'] = '31/12/2014'

In [27]: data2_repr = pprint.pformat(data2)

In [28]: def get_diff(a, b):
    ...:     differ = difflib.unified_diff(a.splitlines(True), b.splitlines(True))
    ...:     return ''.join(line for line in differ if not line.startswith(' '))

In [29]: print(get_diff(data_repr, data2_repr))
--- 
+++ 
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-            'MATURITY_DATE': '2014/12/31',
+            'MATURITY_DATE': '31/12/2014',
```

However this doesn't solve the problem with floating point numbers. You could solve this by first replacing `float`ing points values with `round`ed values to some significant digit, using a simple recursive function.

As far as I know there is no such library that allows this level of fine control over comparisons, so if you want a robust solution you'd better write the whole code yourself.

I'd also point out that maybe you should refactor this data structure into a more structured class, which would make things easier.

Last but not least: you can use `unittest`'s [`addTypeEqualityFunc`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc) to make sure the `TestCase` calls `assertAlmostEqual` when comparing `float`s, without doing it by hand.

---

Now that I think about it you may be able to use `addTypeEqualityFunc` to perform a custom comparison of `dict`s which could add more information on the mismatch. To find *all* mismatches You'd have to use some `except AssertionError as e:` blocks into your custom function, always check all sub-elements and then "join" the error messages somehow. But I don't think the solution would be so clean.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function that has the expected argument and the argument to test and teach each item in the structure individually. You can then give an error description that fits the item to test.

For the complex structure above write multiple of such functions, one for each 'depth'.

E.g.

AssertEqualData(DataToTest, expectedData) that checks one data, which calls AssertInstr

AssertEqualInstr(InstrToTest, expectedInstr) that checks one 'InstrX' element, which calls AssertEqualYield for each item

AssertEqualYield(yieldToTest, expectedYield) that checks one Base or UP element

AssertEqualScenario(scenarioToTest, expectedScenario) that cehcks the Base and Up items.